# Convert double[] to System.array c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm using a visual basic library and one of the methods I'm using calls for a System.Array to be passed into it. 
I've tried using "double[]" and "Object[]" when declaring my array however those will not pass. 
I'm not sure how to convert/declare a "System.Array".

```
Object[] filledVals = new Object[9];                   
xyz.getDoubleArray("NumVoids", out filledVals); //where .getDoubleArray(string, System.Array)
```

Comment: `Array array; xyz.getDoubleArray("NumVoids", out array); double[] doubleArray = (double[])array;`

Comment: It is not passing in an array, you are getting one out via the `out` parameter. There is no need to do a `new` you will already get a `new` back from the function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply declare it as `System.Array`:

```
Array filledVals;
xyz.getDoubleArray("NumVoids", out filledVals);
```

Since it is an `out` parameter, you don't need to initialize it as it *must* be initialized by `getDoubleArray`.

To convert it to a `double[]` you can use this:

```
double[] result = filledVals.OfType<double>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ:

```
System.Array result;              
xyz.getDoubleArray("NumVoids", out result);
var filledVals = result.OfType<double>().ToArray();
```